# error 400 method POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Everytime I run my ajax jquery function I get an error 400

this is my code, the Postman tests are all positive, but when the webapp runner, it does not work, I do not know if it depends on code or html5
Somebody can help me?

JavaScript

```
function add() {

var url= "http://localhost:8080/bip/workAdd";

var work = {
    codiceCommessa: document.getElementById("codiceCommessa").value,
    commessaMainSub: document.getElementById("commessaMainSub").value,
    settoreCliente: document.getElementById("settoreCliente").value,
    nomeCliente: document.getElementById("nomeCliente").value,
    clienteFinale: document.getElementById("clienteFinale").value,
    titoloQuals: document.getElementById("titoloQuals").value,
    keyWorrdsTopic: document.getElementById("keyWordsTopic").value,
    keyWordsActivities: document.getElementById("keyWordsActivities").value,
    anno: parseInt(document.getElementById("anno").value),
    dataInizio: document.getElementById("dataIniziale").value,
    dataFine: document.getElementById("dataFinale").value,
    referente: document.getElementById("referente").value,
    referenteDocumentazione: document.getElementById("referenteDocumentazione").value,
    sviluppatore: document.getElementById("sviluppatore").value,
    path: document.getElementById("path").value


};



$.ajax({

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',

    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: work,

    dataType: "html or json",
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log("saved"),

    },

    error: function (jqXHR, status) {

                    console.log("error")


    }

});
```

Comment: contentType: hasnt ended properly I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function add() {

var url= "http://localhost:8080/bip/workAdd";

var work = {
    codiceCommessa: document.getElementById("codiceCommessa").value,
    commessaMainSub: document.getElementById("commessaMainSub").value,
    settoreCliente: document.getElementById("settoreCliente").value,
    nomeCliente: document.getElementById("nomeCliente").value,
    clienteFinale: document.getElementById("clienteFinale").value,
    titoloQuals: document.getElementById("titoloQuals").value,
    keyWorrdsTopic: document.getElementById("keyWordsTopic").value,
    keyWordsActivities: document.getElementById("keyWordsActivities").value,
    anno: parseInt(document.getElementById("anno").value),
    dataInizio: document.getElementById("dataIniziale").value,
    dataFine: document.getElementById("dataFinale").value,
    referente: document.getElementById("referente").value,
    referenteDocumentazione: document.getElementById("referenteDocumentazione").value,
    sviluppatore: document.getElementById("sviluppatore").value,
    path: document.getElementById("path").value


};



$.ajax({

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',

    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(work),

    dataType: "html or json",
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log("saved"),

    },

    error: function (jqXHR, status) {

                    console.log("error")


    }

});
```

You need to use `JSON.stringify(work)`

Comment: great, now it work, it adds  the element, but it prints "error"

Answer (score 0):

This part is all messed up:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
```

The `contentType` line is correct, but you need to wrap those other options in `headers: { ..... },`

Comment: No, those others should simply be _removed_ ... they are _response_ headers, sending them with the _request_ is utter nonsense to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The server probably doesn't recognize the **data**. You likely need to stringify your JSON.

Comment: now it work, it adds the element, but it prints "error"

Answer (score 0):

The work dictionary you trying to pass into Ajax function should be like
**work = {'a':'b','c':'d'}**
But, as in your case it's like:
**work = {a:'b',c:'d'}**
so, before passing it to ajax change the format of that data as above by using JSON.stringify method.